# Why isn't there a 3D array image in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

In the Vulkan API it was seen as valuable to include a VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_CUBE_ARRAY, but not a 3D array:

```
typedef enum VkImageViewType {
    VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_1D = 0,
    VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D = 1,
    VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_3D = 2,
    VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_CUBE = 3,
    VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_1D_ARRAY = 4,
    VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D_ARRAY = 5,
    VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_CUBE_ARRAY = 6,
} VkImageViewType;
```

Each 6 layers of view for a cube array is another cube. I'm actually struggling to think of a use case for a cube array, and I don't really think it would be useful for 3D array, but why does the cube get an array type and not the 3D image. How is this cube array even supposed to be used? Is there even a cube array sampler?

Comment: I would imagine that a cube array would be used in a similar manner to a texture array, ie bindless management of textures. This could be useful in engines which rely on precomputing many reflection probes around the map.

Comment: "*Is there even a cube array sampler?*" That's something that is pretty simple to just... [look up](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html).

Comment: As for 3D textures, usually I've seen them used for large vector maps or particulate fields (like clouds or fog). Typically you'd only need one instance of that. Additionally an array typically requires that every element be the same size. Given their usage and alignment requirements I'm guessing there was just never any need for them to be added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cube maps, cube map arrays, and 2D array textures are, in terms of the bits and bytes of storage, ultimately the same thing. All of these views are created from the same kind of image. You have to specify if you need a layered 2D image to be usable as an array or a cubemap (or both), but conceptually, they're all just the same thing.

Each mipmap level consists of L images of a size WxH, where W and H shrink based on the original size and the current mipmap level. L is the number of layers specified at image creation time, and it *does not change* with the mipmap level. Put simply, there are a constant number of 2D images per mipmap level. Cubemaps and cubemap arrays require L to be either 6 or a multiple of 6 respectively, but it's still constant.

A 3D image is not that. Each mipmap level consists of a single image of size WxHxD, where W, H, and D shrink based on the original size and current mipmap level. Even if you think of a mipmap level of a 3D image as being D number of WxH images, the number D is not constant between mipmap levels.

These are not the same things.

To have a 3D array image, you would need to have each mipmap level contain L 3D images of size WxHxD, where L is the same for each mipmap level.

---

As for the utility of a cubemap array, it's the same utility you would get out of a 2D array compared to a single 2D image. You use array textures when you need to specify one of a number of images to sample. It's just that in one case, each image is a single 2D image, while in another case, each image is a cubemap.

For a more specific example, many advanced forms of shadow mapping require the use of multiple shadow maps, selected at runtime. That's a good use case for an array texture. You can apply these techniques to point lights through the use of cube maps, but now you need to have the individual images in the array be cube maps, not just single 2D images.

Comment: I see. If I'm using descriptor indexing I'm faced with the options of either placing multiple cubemaps into a cubemap array, or having a different cubemap image and binding them to the right descriptor array element. I can see the disadvantage being more memory use, maybe due to more metadata (more images), and alignment requirements/padding, but I guess it's more versatile (different sized cubemaps depending on what level of detail you want selected at runtime).

Comment: @Zebrafish: Remember that arrays of samplers have the limitation of requiring a dynamically uniform index (unless the implementation allows non-uniform sampler indices). Whereas array textures have no limitations on their array index.

Comment: Dynamically non-uniform indexing of samplers is ok if you enable the feature and ALSO decorate the index with NonUniform( ), right? Non-dynamic indexing is such a cool and powerful features, such as storing attributes in vertices, or giving a stream of IDs to which objects to draw for texture lookup. I wonder if it comes at a high cost. Something tells it's required for ray-tracing?

Comment: @Zebrafish: Optional features are *optional*. Except for [when they're not](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap38.html#features-requirements).

Comment: So if descriptor indexing feature is present, then the device must support non-uniform dynamic indexing of sampled images and storage buffers only, that's it. Not samplers or other types of descriptors. A lot of these rules seem so arbitrary.

Comment: @Zebrafish: Why would you need to index a *sampler* of all things?

Comment: For bindless samplers. I'm assuming without it you'd bind the sampler in the command buffer each time you needed it changed. If you store what type of sampler each drawn object uses then it's part of the drawn object information. Isn't it better that way?

Comment: @Zebrafish: It's a [*sampler*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap13.html). There aren't that many variations of them, and why would it change from object to object at all? It's not even a proper pointer to an actual object.